# Why cannot invoke 'location' with an argument list of type '(GameScene)'

Tags: swift

I type this and Xcode shows the error:

> Cannot invoke 'location' with an argument list of type '(GameScene)'

```
for touch: AnyObject in touches{
    let pointOfTouch = touch.location(self)
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Why are you using `AnyObject` instead of `UITouch`?

Answer (score 0):

You want to get location **in** `GameScene`'s `view`

```
let pointOfTouch = touch.location(in: self.view)
```

also don't specify type of element in a set. If set contains elements of type `UITouch`, each element is `UITouch` which is exactly what you need

```
for touch in touches {
    let pointOfTouch = touch.location(in: view)
}
```